# ruby: rubocop complains on converting if else to case statement

Tags: ruby

I have following if else statement that rubocop complained about `Style/CaseLikeIf: Convert if-elsif to case-when`

```
if obj.is_a? Rest::Headers
  obj
elsif obj.is_a? Hash
  Rest::Headers.new(**obj)
elsif obj.is_a? Array
  Rest::Headers.new(**obj.to_h)
else
  raise 'Invalid object type for Headers!'
end
```

I converted it into case statement

```
case
when (obj.is_a? Rest::Headers)
  obj
when (obj.is_a? Hash)
  Rest::Headers.new(**obj)
when (obj.is_a? Array)
  Rest::Headers.new(**obj.to_h)
else
  raise 'Invalid object type for Headers!'
end
```

But now rubocop complained `Do not use empty case condition, instead use an if expression`. Does anyone know what is wrong with my case statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby wants you to convert to a `case` that matches on the types themselves. `case` in Ruby doesn't just match on equality. A statement of the form

```
case a
when b
  ...
end
```

The case will call `b === a` (note the triple equals here, which does *not* mean equality) and trigger the `when` block if it's true.

`===` is defined on `Object` to be equivalent to `==`, but many classes override it.

- Regular expressions use it to pattern match against the right-hand side
- Ranges check whether the right-hand side is included in the range
- Classes check whether the right-hand side `is_a?` instance of the class.

And it's that third bullet point that Rubocop suggests you use.

```
case obj
when Rest::Headers
  obj
when Hash
  Rest::Headers.new(**obj)
when Array
  Rest::Headers.new(**obj.to_h)
else
  raise 'Invalid object type for Headers!'
end
```

Note that I never explicitly call `is_a?` here; the `case` block automagically knows to do that.

Comment: I did implement that earlier but would that work for Hash and Array? because is_a returns true if class is the class of obj

Comment: @user18646557 *"Classes check whether the right-hand side is_a? instance of the class"* So `Rest::Headers === obj` is identical to `obj.is_a?(Rest::Headers)`. See the the [`===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) documentation of `Module` which is inherited by `Class`.

Comment: @user18646557 Note that Ruby is a duck typing language. So you might be better of not explicitly checking for type, but instead check for available methods. The hash splat operator `**` can splat a given object if it responds to the `to_hash` method. So if `obj.respond_to(:to_hash)` then `Rest::Headers.new(**obj)`. The second check could also be `obj.respond_to(:to_h)` then `Rest::Headers.new(**obj.to_h)`. Just some food for thought.